# How would I make these object legs?

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to create the legs of this bowl. I tried to create the legs from cylinders and attach them but it doesn't look good at all that way. I've tried making handles for cups etc and I've had no issue but I'm kind of stumped on doing legs this way. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possible way:

- Start with a round cube (quadsphere preset) from [Add Mesh Extra
  Objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html#add-mesh-extra-objects) add-on.
- Delete top half of the object
  [image]
- Select groups of faces that will make up the legs
  [image]
- Change pivot point to individual origins with
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (period)
- Run loop tools [circle operator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html?#circle) on the selected faces <kbd>W</kbd> ><kbd>L</kbd> > <kbd>C</kbd>
  [image]
- Extrude by nomals with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then adjust geometry as you need.
  [image]

Comment: Isn't the OP bowl 3 legged?

Comment: @RonJensen the answer is intended to be useful for any user, including the OP. The workflow can easily be adapted to 3 legs. :)

Comment: @Timaroberts thanks so much for your explanation! I've been playing around with it and have been able to get the look I'm going for so far. Much appreciated!

Comment: Perfectly good answer, UV'd,  just adding:  for the 3-legged case, a 1/3 segment of a UV hemisphere,  arrayed in rotation, would be a better starting-point for your method.